# Send specific headers on MIME-type response in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have an Apache Tomcat server running. If I have something like:

```
webapp/
    image1.png
```

Then, I can simply access it using:

```
example.com/image1.png
```

Which is perfect, except that I don't have any control over what headers are being sent. I wish to send specific `Expires` header for certain MIME-types (like, for `image/png`). These headers will be static, so I don't really mind if I have to specify this in some XML file and cannot be dynamic.

Is it possible with Apache Tomcat? The other obvious way is to read from the file and output it to the browser with the appropriate headers, but I think that it might be an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Tomcat Filters for applying this headers.

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <filter>
       <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
       </init-param>
    </filter>
    ...
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
 </web-app>
```

More Info at [Tomcat Filter Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html)

Comment: Your answer seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However, the error I am getting is a ClassNotFoundException for `org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter`. Under `org.apache.catalina.filters.*` I only have: FailedRequestFilter, CsrfPreventionFilter. Any idea how I could get across this?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a workaround.. so I just wrote my own filter which takes care of this. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I think, you can search for a jar containig the class, but it in lib folder of tomcat

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're not using Tomcat 7, but an older version. In my Tomcat 7 installation, I found that filter packaged up in catalina.jar